# Disable Selection of certain TableRow items within TableView in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tablerow

### Starting Point

I would like to implement a `TableView` in which each `TableRow` item will be checked for a certain boolean value. If this value holds true, then this row will be disabled for selection.

For instance I have a `TableView` with 3 `TableRows` (each holds a `Person` object). Now I would like the TableView to make those rows not-selectable whose Person object property is older than 18 years old.

Assume ***2nd row*** fullfills the above condition and is therefore rendered not-selectable. So if my cursor currently is focused on the ***1st row*** and I press the arrow down key, the TableView would **skip** any not-selectable rows (here: ***2nd row***) and select the next available selectable row (here: ***3rd row***)

### My Approach

```
tblLineitems.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<Lineitem>, TableRow<Lineitem>>() {
    public TableRow<Lineitem> call(TableView<Lineitem> tableview) {
        return new TableRow<Lineitem>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Lineitem item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (item == null || empty) {
                } else {
                    itemProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Lineitem> observable, Lineitem oldValue, Lineitem newValue) -> {
                        if (newValue.isOlderThan18()) {
                            setDisable(true);
                        } else {
                            setDisable(false);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```

### My Issue

Although I managed to `setDisable(true)` the affected rows, yet I can still select/mark them with the arrow down and up keys.

Comment: I believe the best solution is to implement your own `SelectionModel`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to filter the list? This will hide rows with defined values like "<18 years old".

Comment: Hi guys, I thought about implementing a FilteredList but my customer persists in having the tableview to display all items but only make certain items not-selectable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around with implementing a custom selection model and a focus model but ended-up using a hack (works for my use case). In my situation, I have to skip at most one row at a time. Therefore, inside the `ChangeListener` of the `selectedItemProperty` I ended up using the following function.

If I encounter an item row I trigger a callback, otherwise I skip the category row.

```kotlin
private fun MyListView.skipCategoryRow(
  previousSelectionIndex: Int,
  currentSelectionIndex: Int
) {
  when {
    currentSelectionIndex > previousSelectionIndex -> selectionModel.selectNext()
    currentSelectionIndex > 1 -> selectionModel.selectPrevious()

    /* prevent moving the selection to index 0, which is always a category row */
    else -> selectionModel.selectNext()
  }
}
```